# Laravel storage sym:link not working in local environment

Tags: laravel, docker, storage, symlink

I am using the default laravel folder structure and the filesystem `public`:

```php
'public' => [
    'driver'     => 'local',
    'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url'        => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Everything runs on docker and the complete laravel folder is mounted into `/var/www/html`:

```yaml
#... Laravel PHP-FPM service definition
  volumes:
    - "./:/var/www/html"
#...
```

When I run `php artisan storage:link` and then `cd /var/www/html/public` and `ls -la` I see that the symlink exists:

`lrwxr-xr-x 1 root root 32 May 5 11:19 storage -> /var/www/html/storage/app/public`

If i then check to see if the linked folder also exists in the container `cd /var/www/html/storage/app/public` everything is there as expected.

Also, when checking `ls -la /var/www/html/public/storage/` directly it shows me the content of the linked folder. So everything is working from symlink perspective

```
# ls -la /var/www/html/public/storage/
total 512
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data    128 May  5 11:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 www-data www-data    352 Apr 19 14:03 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     14 Feb 16 16:58 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 519648 May  5 10:58 sample.png
```

However, when opening the url `/storage/sample.png` the server returns 404.

The remaining contents of `/var/www/html/public` do work fine, so for example `/var/www/html/public/test.png` is visible under `localhost/test.png`.

On production, everything works fine though. Any ideas why the symbolic link is not working on the local system while the link is actually correct?

I already tried removing the storage link and setting the symlink again.

Comment: Is your local web server configured to follow symlinks?

Comment: I added `disable_symlinks off;` to `nginx.conf` `http` directive if that is what you are referring to. Still does not work though.

Comment: What Operating System are you using? (If the answer is Windows, I'm afraid that's your problem - symlinks don't map correctly. If that's the case I will write up an answer with alternative options, citations, etc.)

Comment: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 :)

Comment: Can you try linking using `php artisan storage:link --relative`?

Comment: Tried, storage link is created relative `storage -> ../storage/app/public/` but still 404 unfortunately. thanks mysterious tom

Comment: This weird issue happened to me yesterday when I was running an old project, the problem solved after deleting the existing link and recreating it with `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned that you are using docker. I think the reason that it doesn't work locally, but in production, could be that there is a configuration shift between the two deployments.

For it to work the Nginx container must have access to the storage folder, since it is supposed to serve assets that are located there. I'm guessing that is currently not the case and only the public folder is mounted.

Check if the entire project or both `./public` and `./storage` are mounted into the Nginx container.

Something like this:

```
services:
  #...
  nginx:
   #...
   volumes:
    - "./public:/var/www/html/public:ro"
    - "./storage/app:/var/www/html/storage/app:ro"
    #...
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone running Laravel Sail and Docker, you need to go into the Docker container through the command line or in my case inside Docker Desktop's prebuilt terminal and run the following:

`su sail`   (switches to sail user)

`php artisan storage:link` (adds the sym link into the docker container.

Comment: One of the best answers on WWW.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines on file configuration of nginx:

```
location ^~ /storage/ {
    root "/var/www/html/public/storage/"
}
```

Every time when the request start with `storage`, will access directly the shared path.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to make sure your symlink is created from inside the docker container.

If you run storage:link from outside of your container, the symlink will be relative to your local machine.

Get into the container by running:

```
docker exec -it name_of_your_php_container bash
```

Once you are inside, you should be able to run php artisan

Comment: You can set the symlink relatively to fix this problem as well: `php artisan storage:link --relative`

Comment: @Tom You should move that to a separate answer (also worth to mention that it requires symfony/filesystem package to work)